# Facebook API - POST me/feed - Mentions not working

Tags: facebook, api

I'm testing the ability to post a Facebook status update using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).  There is a lot of out-dated information out there, but judging by the official documentation as well as the data structures returned from `GET /me/feed`, I believe the correct way to do it is:

```
POST /v2.5/me/feed

message: John Doe test
message_tags: {"0":[{"id": "123456","name":"John Doe","type": "user","offset":0,"length":8}]}
```

<sub>*(Note: these are the parameters as entered into the Graph API Explorer, not necessarily as they are encoded in the HTTP request)*</sub>

I've tried setting the id to both the app-scoped-id and an id from taggable_friends,
however this does not actually add a mention - it always shows the whole message as just simple text.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik you can only tag users in Open Graph stories - that´s why the information about tagging is actually in the section about Open Graph stories. You can´t use it for feed posts - prefilling the message would not be allowed anyway.

Comment: Not probably – definitively.

Comment: Found out it is possible to tag with the "tags" field.  These show up as "with John Doe" instead of a mention inside the text though.